# How to let the right toolbar of CartoDB show out?

Tags: carto, toolbar

[image]

How to let the right toolbar of CartoDB show out? My page window is different from that in the guiding video.

Comment: That video is outdated. You are using the new CARTO UI, BUILDER. You can find the right tutorials [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides).

Comment: Thanks for your faithful help！I’m beginner , learning...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're comparing two different things. What you have in your windows is **Map view** and the bottom windows is in **Table view**. In the past, both sections were merged:

[image]

Now, there are pacled in different sections. You can do almost the same things but in different places (there isn't a toolbar with all the tools in the same place).

For example, to make a SQL query you can use Data View:

[image]

Or Map view:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your faithful help！I’m beginner , I get some progress today , but  another question is  coming ...